# Validate if the XML has a tag "string" using XQuery

Tags: xml, xquery

I need to check if the xml has a "OperationResponse" in it and if yes, i need to perform some actions using XQuery. I tried few things and was not successfull. Below is an example of something that i tried.

***Sample XML***

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://examplens/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <ns0:OperationResponse xmlns:ns0="urn:abcd:efgh:bc:1">
         <ns0:DocumentHeader>
            <ns0:Timestamp>2022-12-07T09:30:51+01:00</ns0:Timestamp>
            <ns0:MessageID>abcd</ns0:MessageID>
         </ns0:DocumentHeader>
```

***Sample Code***

```
let $response = xmlMessage.xml
if ( $response[Response[contains(text(),'OperationaResponse')]]  = 'true')
then
"SomeActions"
```

***Expected Output***
A boolean value

Comment: "OperationResponse" is an XML element name. So you need to use `local-name()` function to check for it.

Comment: @yitzhak-khabinsky, I tried "if (local-name($response/*:Envelope/*:Body/*) = 'ns0:OperationResponse')". It is not working is something wrong with the method I have used?

Comment: Please provide a working code example.

Comment: `$response/*:Envelope/*:Body/*` selects all elements inside s:body. If there is more than one local-name will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following.

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/ns0:*[local-name()="OperationResponse"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not build the test into your XQuery:

```
if (.//ns0:OperationResponse)
then (: do your query :)
else () (: return nothing :)
```